# Ввести n предложений и некоторое слово. Найти все предложения, в которых встречается заданное слово и отсортировать в порядке убывания частоты

Tags: c

Ввести n предложений и некоторое слово. Найти все предложения, в которых встречается заданное слово и отсортировать в порядке убывания частоты встречи(т.е сначала идёт предложение, в котором слово встретилось наибольшее количество раз и далее по убыванию)
Часть кода:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char* getstr();
char* word();

int main()
{
    char *str = getstr();
}

char* getstr()
{
    int n = 0;
    printf("Enter number of lines: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char *string;

    for (int i = 1; i<n+1; i++) {
    printf("Print string\n");
    char character;
    int amount_of_characters = 0;
    char *string = (char *)malloc((amount_of_characters+1)*sizeof(char));
    do{
        string = (char *)realloc(string,(amount_of_characters+1)*sizeof(char));
        character = getchar();
        if(character == '.'){
            string[amount_of_characters] = '\0';
        } else if(character == '\n'){
            string[amount_of_characters] = ' ';
        }else {
            string[amount_of_characters] = character;
        }
        amount_of_characters++;
    }while(character != '.');

    }
    return string;
}

char* get_word()
{
    printf("Print word\n");
    char word;
    
}
```

Не понимаю, что делать дальше и правильно ли вообще начал?

Comment: У вас в функции `getstr` когда вы вводите первое предложение, то оно нигде не обрабатывается, а просто затирается следующим предложением. Может лучше назвать функцию `get_words` и она будет возвращать массив слов? Или прям в ней обрабатывать предложение и сразу возвращать результат.